# Select colunas em tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, select

Estou usando o Laravel 5.3 e gostaria de usar colunas de duas tabelas diferentes relacionadas com chave estrangeira:

Por exemplo:

> **Tabela cliente**

```
id | nome   |  end_cep 
 1 | carlos |  69084555
 2 | Maria  |  69088555
```

> **Tabela endereco**

```
   cep    | rua    
 69084555 | Rua grande vitória
 69088555 | Rua Programacao
```

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta

```
  SELECT id, nome, end_cep, e.rua FROM cliente, endereco e WHERE end_cep = e.cep
```

> **Minha Model**

```
class Cliente extends Model
{

    public function cliente(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Endereco', 'end_cep','cep');
    }
}
```

> **Meu controller**

```
$objeto = Cliente::with('endereco')
                    ->select('id','nome','end_cep', 'rua')
                    ->get();
```

Mas está dando como se a coluna rua estivesse desconhecida

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'rua' in 'field
>   list

Sou iniciante no Laravel

Como poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Não seria `end_cep` ao invés de `cep` depois  do `WHERE` na sua consulta?

Comment: Sim. Dei uma errada

Comment: Se não me engano você não pode colocar a coluna `rua` no select, pois o with vai te devolver um objeto endereço que você poderá acessar com `$objeto->endereco->rua`.

Comment: Isso mesmo.. Deu certo. Pode adicionar como resposta, por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu select não precisa passar os nomes das colunas que possui na tabela endereço, neste caso você está passando a coluna `rua` e não se faz necessário.

Retire o mesmo do select e chame o objeto da seguinte forma:

```
$objeto->endereco->rua
```

O endereço é retornado como um objeto e desta forma ai deve funcionar.